# SolrCloud consume all memory when adding my custom field type

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have build custom field type to improve search relevance performance, I have defined the new type, called `text_bag` with this configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text_bag" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="0" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" tokenSeparator="" maxShingleSize="3" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

By the way, size of `synonyms.txt` is very small.

For `schema.xml`, I added these configuration to my collection:

```
<field name="keywords_bag" type="text_bag" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" required="false" />
<copyField source="name" dest="keywords_bag" />
<copyField source="category" dest="keywords_bag" />
<copyField source="location" dest="keywords_bag" />
<copyField source="tags" dest="keywords_bag" />
<copyField source="keywords" dest="keywords_bag" />
```

All of these source fields are just a string with an average length around 100-200 characters and number of items is average around 10-20 items per field.

After deployed these configurations to production workload, for several hours, Solr server consumed all available memory (5GB) which it usually uses just 2GB and uses 100% CPU time.

I'm using Solr 6.5.0 with cloud feature, there are 3 servers in the cluster.

Does anyone notice any issue with configurations?

Comment: So what is the OOM for? Usually OOMs aren't generated because of the analysis chain, but because of some other underlying issue (i.e. cache too large, sorting by too many distinct fields, too many updates happening at the same time, etc.)

Comment: @MatsLindh Sorry for titled with OOM, in my current situation, Solr node (leader) is consuming all available memory but not actually throw java OOM. All I have changed was just adding field and custom type, after rolled all configuration back, the situation back to normal.

So what I suspect is that whether index or query chain causes the problem but I cannot try it in production again.

It's interesting that you suspect the underlying issue, especially too many updates, as I dig some graph, leader node is the first who consume all memory.

Can you elaborate more on that issue?

Comment: How are you committing? Seeing as you're now doubling the amount of data, you may just have too much data in memory before it being persisted compared to earlier.

Comment: I use commit=true&softCommit=true parameters for update request. Each update request comtains about 2000 docs including update existing and add new document but mostly would be the update (90%). The total docs sent to solr is about 500k.

Comment: I'm trying to do shadow testing with production load, if I find something, will post an update, maybe on tuesday.

Comment: Use commitWithin instead, that way you can index documents in parallel without Solr having to contend with multiple commit requests.

Comment: @MatsLindh I just found that memory leak is on query side. I dump Solr heap and found that all thread holding a large number of SpanNearQuery objects when I put ShingleFilter as part of query analyzer. I'll test with other Solr version and then will report the bug. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After tested with many query patterns, ShingleFilter can produce a large number of terms which cause QueryParser to process those terms so it would require large amount of memories.

I tested with Solr 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 7.0.1 with -Xmx1g then passing 15 terms to this query analyzer, it just takes 10 concurrent requests and it consumes all 1GB memory without responding the request on time.

I already sent an issue here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-12084